# Processing an XMPP message on the sever before it is delivered?

Tags: xmpp, smack, translate

I am new to XMPP and I am wondering if it is possible to intercept an XMPP message at the server to perform some processing on it before delivering it to the recipient. What I would like to do is translate the text before it reaches the recipient. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: On the client or on the server ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Of course depends on implementation (so basically on your chat server). With Openfire for example it's possible to develop a plugin PacketInterceptor to do what you are looking for)

Comment: Yes, on the server side I would like to intercept. Thanks a lot Mickaël Rémond.